# Relationship between primitive roots and quadratic residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots

I understand that if $g$ is a primitive root modulo an odd prime $p$, then Euler's Criterion tells us that $g$ cannot be a quadratic residue.

My question is, does this result generalize to prime powers? That is, if $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p^m$ for an odd prime $p$, must $g$ be a quadratic non-residue?

I spent a little while trying to come up with a proof but was unable to achieve anything useful so any proofs (or counterexamples) are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of a quadratic residue modulo $n$ divides $\varphi(n)/2$. A primitive root has order $\varphi(n)$. Hence a primitive root is always a quadratic nonresidue.

Comment: Looks like you beat me by 11 seconds :)

Comment: Ahh so simple I cannot believe I did not see this! Thank you

Comment: So If I have a group formed using roots of unity, this group does not contain all of the quadratic residues?

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends I don't understand your question, sorry. Can you explain the situation you're asking about more?

Comment: My fault, let me try again: If I have a set of nth roots of unity : {1, w, w^2, w^3, ...,w^n-1}, Would all of these elements be quadratic residues?

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends Roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$? Like $w = \exp(2\pi i/n)$? These live in a different world than quadratic residues generally. "Quadratic residue" makes only sense modulo something. That something is usually a positive integer (but one can generalise the notion), and if the integer in question is clear from the context, its mention is often omitted, so one speaks just of "quadratic residues" instead of "quadratic residues modulo $m$", which would be correct. A quadratic residue modulo $m$ is then a (relatively prime) congruence class modulo $m$.

Comment: For example the quadratic residues modulo $9$ are the congruence classes of $1,4$, and $7$ modulo $9$. These are different kinds of objects than complex roots of unity. If you are talking about "$n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity modulo $m$", that is, of integers (or congruence classes modulo $m$) that satisfy $a^n \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, then we have the same kind of objects, and whether all $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity modulo $m$ are quadratic residues modulo $m$ depends on the relation between $n$ and $\varphi(m)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahh, I was getting mixed up. I will need to re-read your helpful comments, but it vaguely makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Can we say every nonresidue of p is also a primitive root of p? If yes than every prime has at least $(p-1)/2$ primitive roots?

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is a primitive root, then the quadratic residues are precisely those elements which are even powers of $g$, so that if $g$ is a primitive root, then it cannot be a quadratic residue (since $g$ is an odd power of $g$)
.